# Change toolbar background color in TextAngular

Tags: textangular

How to change the background color?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The background is part of the element with a class of 'ta-toolbar'.

In your stylesheet, add

```
.ta-toolbar { background-color: #fff; }
```